# Dynamically formed http request

Tags: forms, angular, http

I need to send get request like this to my api:

```
http://test.example.com/api/activity/search?word={word}&age={age}&free={free}
```

and then show this activities in my page with *ngFor, but when user fill inputs, i need to dynamically insert values in unnecessary arguments of this.
What i already done:

```
//activity.service.ts :
    searchActivities(word?: any, age?: any, free?: any) {
    let w, a, f;
//contat values from forms here
    w = word     ? `word=${word}` : '';
    a = age      ? `age=${age}` : '';
    f = free     ? `free=${free}` : '';

    return this.http.get(`http://test.example.com/api/activity/search?${w}${a}${f}`);
}
```

as you noticed, i miss ampersands here, and it works only with one input, for example when user wants to see all free football activities, he can't.

In my component i have this:

```
activities = [];
args: any[] = [null, null, null]; //array for values
//funtction attached to input's events
setArgument(index, value) {
      this.args[index] = value; //fills array with values from inputs
      this.activityService
    // spread operator gives error in typescript for some reason, so i decided to put arguments this way
      .searchActivities(this.args[0], this.args[1], this.args[2])
      .subscribe((data: Response) => this.activities = data.json());
    }
```

example of inputs:

```
<md-checkbox (click)="setArgument(5, !IsFree)" [(ngModel)]="IsFree" name="free">Free</md-checkbox>
<md-input-container>
    <input (focusout)="setArgument(0, word)" [(ngModel)]="word" name="word" mdInput placeholder="Search word">
</md-input-container>
```

I hope you understood what i'm trying to do, i'm novice at programming and maybe i do it completely bad way. Please advice how can i deal with ampersands, and maybe simplify or rewrite this code somehow

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#search-parameters (of course, this is also valid for the Http service, not only for the Jsonp service).

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what i was looking for, but couldn't find and started to write this terrible code ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution to your ampersand problem would be [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=control)

So you might add code similar to the following:

```
w = word     ? `word=${word}` : '';
a = age      ? `age=${age}` : '';
f = free     ? `free=${free}` : '';

q = [w, a, f].filter(function(x) { return x !== '' }).join('&');

return this.http.get(`http://test.example.com/api/activity/search?${q}`);
```

So you create an array containing all of your query strings, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) out the ones that are empty, and the join together into a string separated with ampersand characters.